# How to create a multiple crosstab report in jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I would like to create a multiple cross tabs report using iReport Designer Professional 4.7.0. Please find the sample screenshot of the same below.

I was able to do everything accept the Total's row showing the type wise totals.

Thanks in advance

[image]