# centering and mergre row crosstab (jasper report)

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to run a simple jasper report (crosstab) where the first column contains the same values as below:

```
Besmir  20
Besmir  21
Besmir  22
```

What I need is to merge the first column into something like this : PDF

```
        20
Besmir  21
        22
```

And I generate to Excel this fails.

```
Besmir  20


        21
        22
```

I tried with deselecting print repeated values but only the first row is printed.

Please let me know if somebody ever found a solution to this.

**** Good working for PDF. But not work generate to EXCEL. ****

[THIS PIC EXAM IN CROSSTAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082897/how-to-create-a-multiple-crosstab-report-in-jasper)